# Need help understanding some code sample?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, anonymous-types

Recently while browsing through recent c# question/answers in this forum I stumbled upon a piece of linq-to-xml code than I cannot fully understand but being someone who likes working with linq-to-xml it bugs me as I cannot figure out the what the process is exactly doing in a step by step manner.

Here is the code snippet

```
var cons = xdoc.Descendants("xref")
.Where(x=>x.Attribute("rid").Value.Contains("ref"))
.GroupBy(x=>x.Parent)
.Select(grp=> new
        {
            Parent = grp.Key,
            ConsecutiveNodes = grp.Select((n, i)=> new
                                          {
                                            Index = i+1,
                                            Node = n
                                          }),
            Count = grp.Count()
        })
.ToList();
```

Can anyone explain to me in detail the part

```
.Select(grp=> new
        {
            Parent = grp.Key,
            ConsecutiveNodes = grp.Select((n, i)=> new
                                          {
                                            Index = i+1,
                                            Node = n
                                          }),
            Count = grp.Count()
        })
```

is doing? I've never used a anonymous type inside another anonymous type and I also don't get multi-parameter lambda expression `(n,i)=>new...` (except the simple thing that one parameter is character and the other is index)? What is it doing exactly in this code?

Here is the file(posted by the OP of the code) [xml file](https://codeshare.io/5wOjlK)

Comment: Do you have the XML that you are working with? This may be helps us explain it in a better way

Comment: @G_S I've updated the question and added the same link as the OP posted...

Comment: It is a nested dictionary : Dictionary<key, Dictionary<key, object>>

Comment: @jdweng could you please elaborate on it?

Comment: Look at Michael's answer.  I would change code.  If it is failing try following : .GroupBy(x=>(string)x.Parent)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets understand the Linq by breaking your query into 2 parts

First part

```
        var cons = xdoc.Descendants("xref")
                     .Where(x => x.Attribute("rid").Value.Contains("ref"))
                     .GroupBy(x => x.Parent);
```

Second part

```
        var consSelect = cons.Select(grp => new
                     {
                         Parent = grp.Key,
                         ConsecutiveNodes = grp.Select((n, i) => new
                         {
                             Index = i + 1,
                             Node = n
                         }),
                         Count = grp.Count()
                     })
                     .ToList();
```

In the first part, you are getting all xref and grouping your XML by its parent.
Whenever you group an element, the grouped element will be considered as key.

So in the second part, grp.key gives you parent element, count gives you number of xref's in your each group, Consecutive nodes is again a collection of {index, Node } object, which contains each xref as node and 'i' as Index (i is a simply an iterator)

Answer (score 1):

the Select method has an overload that let you use the index

[you can see the documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx)